# How to fix following error when using Android Image Cropper library: Cannot resolve symbol 'OnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener'

Tags: android

I have an activity that uses Android Image Cropper library for cropping. I keeping getting this error Cannot resolve symbol 'OnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener' which I spent days trying to solve without any success.

Here is the MainActivity.java where the error is occurring:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

public class  MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  CropImageView.OnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener,  CropImageView.OnSetImageUriCompleteListener {

    private CropImageView mCropImageView;

    private View mProgressView;

    private Uri mCropImageUri;

    private TextView mProgressViewText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mCropImageView = (CropImageView)  findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
        mProgressView =  findViewById(R.id.ProgressView);
        mProgressViewText = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.ProgressViewText);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mCropImageView.setOnSetImageUriCompleteListener(this);
        mCropImageView.setOnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mCropImageView.setOnSetImageUriCompleteListener(null);
        mCropImageView.setOnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener(null);
    }

    public void onLoadImageClick(View view) {
        CropImage.startPickImageActivity(this);
    }

    public void onCropImageClick(View view) {
        mCropImageView.getCroppedImageAsync(mCropImageView.getCropShape(), 500,  500);
        mProgressViewText.setText("Cropping...");
        mProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void  onSetImageUriComplete(CropImageView cropImageView, Uri uri, Exception error) {
        mProgressView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (error != null) {
            Log.e("Crop",  "Failed to load image for cropping", error);
            Toast.makeText(this,  "Something went wrong, try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void  onGetCroppedImageComplete(CropImageView view, Bitmap bitmap, Exception error) {
        mProgressView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (error == null) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Crop",  "Failed to crop image", error);
            Toast.makeText(this,  "Something went wrong, try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int  requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);

            // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage,
            // but we don't know if we need to for the URI so the simplest is to try open the stream and see if we get error.
            boolean requirePermissions = false;
            if (CropImage.isReadExternalStoragePermissionsRequired(this, imageUri)) {

                // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
                requirePermissions = true;
                mCropImageUri = imageUri;
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            }

            if (!requirePermissions) {
                mCropImageView.setImageUriAsync(imageUri);
                mProgressViewText.setText("Loading...");
                mProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (mCropImageUri != null && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mCropImageView.setImageUriAsync(mCropImageUri);
            mProgressViewText.setText("Loading...");
            mProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Required permissions are not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I just added the build.gradle file for additional information:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.paigger.imagecroppercutomui"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Xml file isn't needed. Your build.gradle is

Comment: It should be OnCropImageCompleteListener. Link from library repo: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/cropper/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/CropImageView.java#L1983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnCropImageCompleteListener` instead of `OnGetCroppedImageCompleteListener`
There is no such interface in this library.
You can look at the view class [here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/5fb46a6c2efa6ce53d0a56ded5ea9adf992d7ad9/cropper/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/CropImageView.java)